# MySQLi/PHP - How can I display total "number" of users that chose one side vs the other?

Tags: php, mysqli, count

This is as detailed as possible.

I have 2 forms used for pre-registration for an upcoming game. Depending on which form someone fills out, will depend on the side they are registering for. Regardless both forms insert data into the same table and everything is working great for that part.

The issue Im running into is when I try to display the count for the number of times a certain side (red or blue) is used in the database, nothing is displayed.

The end result should show something like "3 vs 2" on the page so people can see it and have it update automatically when new info is submitted.

Where 3 is the current total of times the "blue" side has been chosen and 2 is the current total of times the "red" side has been chosen.

The table name is "game_checkin" and the column for the sides is "side". The two possible answers are "red" or "blue". Both are hidden fields.

Both of my forms looks like this:

```
<form action="/pre-reg.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br/>
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" maxlength="2" required><br/>
<input type="text" name="location" placeholder="City, ST" required><br/>
<input type="text" name="callsign" placeholder="Callsign" maxlength="12" required>
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date ('m-d-Y');?>">
<input type="hidden" name="side" value="blue"> red has a value of "red"...
<input type="submit" value="Check In">
</form>
```

This is the current code I use. I supplied an open area for anyone wanting to tell me what I'm missing.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbname");
// Verify Connection - duh!
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
 echo "You kicked my doge and now he no pee straight:<br/>" 
       . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


///// SCHOOL ME HERE \\\\\


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Like I mentioned, 
I need to know how to display the total "number" of users that chose "blue" vs "red". 
Then echo it to the page, for example like: 3 vs 2

my resources: mysql 5, php 5, phpmyadmin, linux os, paid hosting...

I have been stuck on this for the past few days trying to find an answer everywhere I could look. If you can help, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `( SELECT count(id) as cblue FROM table WHERE side="blue" )
UNION
(  SELECT count(id) as cred FROM table WHERE side="red" )`
What about something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually kinda trivial...

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select `side`, count(*) from `game_checkin` group by `side`");
$sides = array("blue"=>0,"red"=>0);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) $sides[$row[0]] = $row[1];

echo $sides['blue']." vs ".$sides['red'];
```